# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: prototypejs

this error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function keeps getting thrown it is part if the prototype.js  I didn't write the website but it seems to be causing lots of errors on other items.  What is the cause of this? Thanks

```
var Enumerable = (function() {
      function each(iterator, context) {
        var index = 0;
        try {
          this._each(function(value) {
            iterator.call(context, value, index++);
          });
        } catch (e) {
          if (e != $break) throw e;
        }
        return this;
      }
```

Comment: Can you use the Javascript console in your browser and show further up the stack trace to find out where its begin called from?

Answer (score 0):

The object being enumerated is probably not enumerable. Look into the code anywhere you have .each() and make sure a valid object/array is being passed onto it.